# what does dense_[number] mean in model.summary in keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I'm unable to understand what does `dense_13`,`dense_14` represent in this picture.[image]

Clearly it doesn't show any relation with the properties of that dense layer.

Answer (score 1):

The number is automatically generated by keras, starting from 1, each time you create a new layer instance of the same, so the autogenerated names of layers are unique and do not clash between each other.